# npm opencv will not install Tried to download(403): https://node- opencv.s3.amazonaws.com/o

Tags: opencv

I want to install opencv to use smartcrop.
I received opencv version 2.4.9.
Node Version 6.10.2
I am using version 3.10.10 of npm.
I get a long error message. And it can not be installed.

```
> opencv@6.0.0 install C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\opencv
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-
opencv.s3.amazonaws.com/o
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for opencv@6.0.0 and 
node@6.10.2

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! opencv@6.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv@6.0.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --
fallb
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the opencv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs opencv
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls opencv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```